# Recover data from partition

Tags: data-recovery

If I accidentally clicked "Erase entire disk", what can I do to recover my previous partitions? Just after clicking Next with "Erase entire disk" selected, I realized my mistake and didn't go any further but now i cant start the previous windows 7 and i cant see the partition anymore.i tried boot-repair from ubuntu session and nothing.Can my data be saved?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not recover a deleted partition after using "erase disk" you have erased the partition and all data on the disk you can reformat it and and create a new partition to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: what "erase entire disk" do ? erasing only partition table or savings 0x00 to entire disk like ntsfwipe does ?

Comment: Np please remember to close this question if you find the answer satisfactory by clicking the ChecKMarK; it overrides the disk in 00 mode